# Bash command with $(subcommand) not working in make

Tags: bash, docker, shell, makefile

this is in my makefile:

```
docker-rm:
  docker rm $(docker ps -aq)
```

and when I run it, I get this:

```
$ make docker-rm
docker rm 
"docker rm" requires at least 1 argument.
See 'docker rm --help'.

Usage:  docker rm [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [CONTAINER...]

Remove one or more containers
make: *** [Makefile:15: docker-rm] Błąd 1
```

It is not that I have no containers to remove, because when I run docker command without makefile it works fine:

```
$ docker rm $(docker ps -aq)
463323e2bcf0
eef08f265387
2152910c6fe6
d7e7e9aff4e2
82875b1966c9
2d9295c8d32d
b9a45885e45d
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to quote `$` in Makefile's.

```
docker-rm:
        docker rm $$(docker ps -aq)
```